# TomTom GPS 1500 loads cdc_ether and usbnet modules, thinks it's a USB ethernet device :(

Tags: 14.04, drivers

Patch-current Ubuntu 14.04.3, Dell Latitude D630, TomTom GPS 1500. `uname -a` = `Linux wombat 3.13.0-65-generic #105-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 21 18:50:58 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

When I plug the TomTom 1500 GPS into my USB port, `dmesg -T` shows:

```
[Wed Sep 30 20:29:23 2015] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[Wed Sep 30 20:29:23 2015] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1390, idProduct=5454
[Wed Sep 30 20:29:23 2015] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[Wed Sep 30 20:29:23 2015] usb 2-1: Product: TomTom
[Wed Sep 30 20:29:23 2015] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Linux 2.6.28.10 with dwc_otg_pcd
[Wed Sep 30 20:29:23 2015] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: BL6443A#####
[Wed Sep 30 20:29:23 2015] cdc_ether 2-1:2.0 usb0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:1d.7-1, CDC Ethernet Device, 02:04:06:08:0a:0c
```

and it shows up as a USB Ethernet adapter.

I added `blacklist cdc_ether` to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist` (I guess I should have used `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-cdc_ether.conf` instead).

After a reboot, same result. When I `sudo rmmod cdc_ether usbnet` the TomTom vanishes. `lsusb` shows:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1390:5454 TOMTOM B.V.
```

After I changed the filename to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-cdc_ether.conf`, on replugging the TomTom 1500, `dmesg -T` shows:

```
[Wed Sep 30 21:37:39 2015] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[Wed Sep 30 21:37:42 2015] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[Wed Sep 30 21:37:43 2015] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1390, idProduct=5454
[Wed Sep 30 21:37:43 2015] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[Wed Sep 30 21:37:43 2015] usb 2-1: Product: TomTom
[Wed Sep 30 21:37:43 2015] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Linux 2.6.28.10 with dwc_otg_pcd
[Wed Sep 30 21:37:43 2015] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: BL6443A#####
```

No other module claimed the TomTom 1500, so Ubuntu doesn't see it.

How can I presuade Ubuntu to force the TomTom 1500 to look like something other than a USB ethernet?

I finally got a response from TomTom Tech support (summary: I Lose):

Staff Account XXXXXXXX. (US) via E-mail 02/02/2016 04:38 PM
Dear Walt,

Thank you for contacting TomTom Customer Support regarding your TomTom VIA device. My name is XXXXXX and I will be assisting you today.

The reference number for your query is ######-######.

Due to higher than normal email volume, we apologize for the delay in responding to your query. Any inconvenience caused is deeply regretted.

Walt, as I understand from your email you want to know if you can update the device on a LINUX operating system. I’m glad that you emailed us and I will provide you with more information.

I am sorry to inform you that the application MyDrive Connect is only supported for Windows and Mac operating systems and unfortunately we are unable to provide support for Linux based operating systems. I will pass on this feedback to our concerned team so that TomTom could support even the Linux based operating systems.

---

And, he sent me a link to a "these are the versions of Windows and MacOS we support" page, asserting it was "more information on MyDrive compatibility.", and expressing the hope that it would be "helpful". Since TomTom GPS run embedded Linux, I'm puzzled.

I guess the only way I can recover from my mistaken purchase is to instantiate a virtual machine, and get Windows to run there. Makes me feel dirty (and stupid).

Comment: probably enable/disable wlan of devices makes differences with output of lsusb and of dmesg -

Comment: @dschinn1001: Nonsense! When I plugged it in, I was using a wired connection and WiFi was off. How could "enable/disable wlan of devices" affect it?

Comment: it is not nonsense, when you disable wlan then you have different results, and when you would perform a kind of flash to the chipsets of given device, then hidden hardware-details can pop up after reboot ... I did this flash to aldi medion tablet and then it was visible that inside was built-in lenovo tablet - but you might be right about that this chip flash is not working on every device. You should know today that since 2003 we have more hybrid devices who are piece by piece different.

Comment: TomTom is perpetually online with wlan ! because it is a navigator (nazigator) ... with GPS built inside for its geo-caching functionality.

Comment: I repeat what I said before. Nonsense! `wlan0` was disabled. What do you mean by "when you would perform a kind of flash to the chipsets of given device"?

Comment: @dschinn1001: That's just rude. Why would I want to flash (install) some other software on my device (which is not just a "chip")?  Which software? You say "an example for a flash-listing is here" where? Link missing. I'll look at the "chip reset" program - put it on pastebin or dropbox or some other file sharing site and post the link, so others reading this can see, too.

Comment: + sorry for being rude, but I understood you as if you were not quite clear about hardware-specifications so I thought just the idea would be to flash the chipset a bit for to tickle more details out of navigator. I had made a chipreset with that aldi-tablet and then it was visible that there a lenovo was built-in as mainboard. Before chip-reset this lenovo was not visible in dmesg. But when you have a w-lan device you need a dead (=wlan-free) space in your house (cellar ?) for to make successful a chip-reset ...

Comment: I could send you an example for chip-reset, but you would have to modify it for your use (or feel free to improve it) ...

Comment: @dschinn1001:  I repeat: I'll look at the "chip reset" program - put it on pastebin or dropbox or some other file sharing site and post the link, so others reading this can see, too. I've been programming for 49 years, so I'm comfortable with modifying it. Since you are right on the edge of being classified (by me) as being a Troll/Random Noise Source (in this case, at least), I will not share my email address.

Comment: have posted it here. Feel free to mail me your improvements and suggestions and your reviews - http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/14907062/

Comment: @dschinn1001: See http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/14910497/ . In summary, this poorly documented, poorly formatted, burdened with
unneeded #includes and unused variables, reads local memory (from the
stack), does NOT look at (or even for) the USB-connected TomTom VIA
1500/1505 GPS - it is a Piece of Crap, and completely unsuited for my
purpose.
It shows little understanding of C, programming in general, or the product that is the subject of my question.

Comment: you dont have recognized anything after reboot ? there should be different result with dmesg of usb-devices ... and at least an a bit brighter display than before ... thank you for you criticisms - they are plain logically referring to knowledge of IT. There are two different sorts of fools. Those who are blended by success and those who are blended by knowledge. (included me and you as fools).

Comment: Your last question shows that you have not even read my question thoroughly. This completes your classification by me as a Troll/Random Noise Source. Thanks for playing. I will never again respond to anything you say.

Comment: + I already said and have written, that you may improve the listing as given to you and you can direct the binary of this listing to your usb-port when you are smart enough, so dont discriminate me +

Answer (score 3):

To TS: Your Tomtom VIA 1500 is running navcore version newer then 9.  Navcore is the OS/GUI image that Tomtom uses. Older TomToms (XL, GO, etc) were using older Navcore, which, when connected into a PC, would reboot, and present itself as a USB disk.

Devices that run navcore 10+ now run OS all the time, and when connected to PC, present themselves as an Ethernet over USB device (which is clearly what your device does as well).  Update is performed by establishing a TCP/IP session to a device (most likely using SSL encryption, I have not investigated much).  Generally, Tomtom device runs a DHCP server, and has an IP 169.254.255.1, and serves up IP 169.254.255.2/30 to the computer.

If you configured networking over USB correctly, you should be able to access the http server on your Tomtom VIA by using the URL http://169.254.255.1/pcmi/?locale=en_gb

There is no known (to me) way to downgrade navcore in TomTom VIA devices down to 9.x.

HTH